# Calling an ImageJ macro on files in a specific order

Tags: r, macros, imagej

I am new to ImageJ so I'm not even exactly sure what I should be searching for to find an answer to this question.

I have a bunch of image files in one folder (TIF). I already wrote a macro to split the files into RGB channels and then save them to the same directory. The output is thus something like this:

```
-File 1-blue.tif
-File 1-green.tif
-File 1-red.tif
-File 2-blue.tif
-File 2-green.tif
...
etc.
```

Next I am using the [JACoP plugin](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/track/jacop.html) which takes two image files and computes various kinds of correlation coefficients/analysis between the inputs. For each directory, I want to do the following:

Set global settings:

1. Set a parameter in the threshold tab
2. Select "Pearson's coefficients" and "M1 and M2 coefficients" under analysis to perform

Then loop through the following for each file in my directory:

3. Set input file one to File X (red) and file two to File X (blue)
4. Click Analyze
5. Set input file one to File X (red) and file two to File X (green)
6. Click Analyze
7. Set input file one to File x (blue) and file two to File x (green)
8. Click Analyze

Then finally:

9. Save the analysis output log

The problem is that I don't know how to tell ImageJ how to call each of the color files in that order. How do I specify that it pulls out the files in chunks of three, analyses them, and then moves on to the next chunk of three?

I just need some basic help on the general algorithm and possible functions I might need to get me started - I can write the actual macro code myself.

**EDIT:** It has just occurred to me that I may be able to pass the files to an ImageJ macro in sets of three by using R. Something like this:

```
file_list <- list.files(getwd())
rgbFiles <- file_list[grep(pattern = "blue|green|red", file_list)]
rgbFilesSplit <- split(rgbFiles, ceiling(seq_along(rgbFiles)/3))
```

So after setting the working directory, I just extract out the rgb files and split them into a list.

If this approach is valid, how would I then call an ImageJ macro on each of the files described in the sublist? I already know how to call the macro and specify the input directory using the R system() function but how would I get ImageJ to receive input files which are just file name strings generated from the R code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Calling-an-ImageJ-macro-on-files-in-sets-of-3-td5013674.html). The user Joost Willemse was very helpful in forming my final macro. Here is the full macro:

```
dir=getDirectory("Choose a Directory");
list = getFileList(dir);
Array.sort(list);

for (i=0; i<list.length; i+=3) {
    open(list[i]);
    blue=getTitle;

    open(list[i+1]);  
    green=getTitle;

    open(list[i+2]);
    red=getTitle;

    run("JACoP ", "imga="+red+" imgb="+blue+" thra=648 thrb=517 pearson mm");
    run("JACoP ", "imga="+red+" imgb="+green+" thra=648 thrb=517 pearson mm");
    run("JACoP ", "imga="+blue+" imgb="+green+" thra=648 thrb=517 pearson mm");

    close(red);
    close(green);
    close(blue);
}
```

After setting the directory, the for loop begins. `i+=3` lets the iterator count in steps of three (I didn't know this was possible when I asked the question)! Now each of the three images are opened and their titles are saved. Finally, the titles are send into the string portion of the `run()` function via concatenation. Then the images are closed. As long as your list is sorted correctly in the directory before you begin this should work just fine. **Make sure you set your thresholds in the `run()` function for JACoP!!**

Additionally, I stripped the coefficient values from the log using `grep()` and `gsub()` in R. Not the most efficient way of doing it but it gets the job done. You can modify this code as necessary for whatever you are pulling from the log file:

```
# This function takes the path to the log file. It then removes the Pearson's Coefficent, Manders M1/M2, and thresholded Manders M1/M2. It then gathers them into a table. 
extract <- function(data){
    dat <- read.table(data, header = FALSE, sep = "", fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dat <- dat[ , "V1"]
    coef <- dat[grep(pattern = "=", dat)]
    coef <- as.numeric(gsub("r=|M1=|M2=", "",coef))
    coef <- split(coef, ceiling(seq_along(coef)/5))
    coef <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, coef)
    names(coef) <- c("r", "M1", "M2", "M1(T)", "M2(T)")
    coef <- cbind(Value = c("Red/Blue", "Red/Green", "Blue/Green"), coef)

    return(coef)
}
```

Note that `coef <- as.numeric(gsub("r=|M1=|M2=", "",coef))` will need to be modified depending on what you are extracting from the log file. Same goes for `coef <- split(coef, ceiling(seq_along(coef)/5))` - change the 5 to the number of things being reported by the log file.

```
# Now just split the table into a list for each of the different analysis combinations fed into JACoP. Here I assume you set the output of the extract function to "dat".

output <- split(dat, dat$Value)
```

The output is a list of all the analysis values for each image fed into the macro divided by the different JACoP color channels analyzed. For example:

```
$`Red/Blue`                 
Value       r           M1          M2          M1(T)       M2(T)
Red/Blue    0.743871077 0.395698602 0.963246489 0.513951407 0.700130944
Red/Blue    0.460021089 0.605613993 0.456788982 0.125648321 0.424468211
Red/Blue    0.967115553 0.357528694 0.767577893 0.073250688 0.720399867

$`Red/Green`                
Value       r           M1          M2          M1(T)       M2(T)
Red/Green   0.79367778  0.36556424  0.722980958 0.487698812 0.381559727
Red/Green   0.262211518 0.063695185 0.653330753 0.276610328 0.132548249
Red/Green   0.483240639 0.348516661 0.961846834 0.832706515 0.356203613

$`Blue/Green`                   
Value       r           M1          M2          M1(T)       M2(T)
Blue/Green  0.549159913 0.834823152 0.389143503 0.655878106 0.446664812
Blue/Green  0.144388419 0.844781823 0.534304211 0.79041495  0.844326066
Blue/Green  0.805481028 0.344139017 0.490682901 0.246814106 0.641006611
```